# IntelliJ problem setup JDK (compiles properly but keep seeing errors)

Tags: java, windows, intellij-idea, view, ide

I have a problem with my IntelliJ : it is able to launch my project and make it work properly (because the JDK is set up correctly), but the view of my project is full of errors, like if it did not know the JDK, and it keeps asking me to set up the JDK. Here are some screens :

[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENlSl.png)

I tried to invalidate caches and restart, but it did not change anything. I repeat, I can successfully launch this project, this is just about the view. This is really bothersome, could someone help me please ?

Thank you in advance,

Virgile Petermannn

Answer (score 0):

Try this. first, clear your local cache files and then download dependencies.

```
rm -rf $HOME/.gradle/caches/
./gradlew build --refresh-dependencies
```

Comment: I use Windows, not Linux, but thank you for helping !

Answer (score 0):

Remove JDK configuration in IntelliJ IDEA, reinstall JDK, add JDK configuration again in Settings (Preferences) | Project structure | SDKs.

Comment: @VirgilePetermann Please accept the answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work .